# How do I force one specific key to come at the top of a python dict or JSON dump

Tags: python, json, sorting, key

**Context**

I'm converting a log into a `JSON` object using `python`. This makes placing the data into our `SIEM` a piece of cake. I set all of the data how I want it into a `python dict`, then run `json.dumps` on it. Great.

**Problem**

However, I need a particular field at the top of the `dict/json object`. At ingestion, this field is looked for by our `SIEM`, and our `SIEM` will only look so many bytes into the event. The problem is that when sorted `(json.dump sort_keys=True)`, this field is always towards the bottom of the event... too far away for our `SIEM` to catch it!

**Question**

How can I manually force this particular key to come first in the json output? I'm not seeing an easy way.

Comment: Let me get that straight: your SIEM chooses to ignore parts of valid messages? I'd call that a big, fat ***BUG*** or negligence. Either way, I'd like to know which system you are using. ;) You might want to inform the vendor.

Comment: Well, yes I suppose it does. It only looks X bytes into each event because it would be impossible to look over ALL of the events with the regex pattern matcher. We're talking millions of events a minute.

The amount of bytes it looks through can be defined, but not quite realistic to go much farther.

Comment: Well, sure. Still, it sounds like a bad, bad idea. If a single server can't handle the intake, it is a better idea to scale out than to rely on the order of fields in a format for which the specification explicitly states that is unordered: "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs." What horrifies me is that a vendor trusted with security concerns seems to be unable to read the specs.